# calculator on JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I have recently encountered a  question during an interview to implement a calculator using functions in JavaScript as follows:

```
five(plus(one()));     //returns 6
seven(minus(one())); // returns 6
```

How would I implement it?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Stack Overflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach could be to create a function, `getNumber(x)` which will return a function (call it *foo*). *Foo* accepts an operator function as input and applies the operator function to `x`. However, in your example, the operator function for a number is not always given (eg: `one()`), and so, if this is the case, the operator function will default to the [*identity function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function), which will return the number `x` (eg: `one()` needs to return `1`) if the operator is not supplied.

You can also create a function `setOperator` where you can supply an operator function on two numbers (`x` and `y`) which is then later called on the result of calling your number functions. The operator function takes in `y`, which then returns a new function which takes in `x`. As you can see by your usage of the functions (eg: `five(plus(one()))`) `one()` is supplied to the operator first, and then `5` is supplied when calling our *foo* function, thus, we need to accept `y` first, and then `x`.

See example below:

```js
const getNumber = x => (f = x => x) => f(x);
const setOperator = f => y => x => f(x, y);

const five = getNumber(5);
const one = getNumber(1);
const seven = getNumber(7);

const plus = setOperator((x, y) => x+y);
const minus = setOperator((x, y) => x-y);

console.log(five(plus(one()))); // 6
console.log(seven(minus(one()))); // 6
```

Comment: Very nice, but I'd define `getNumber` as `f ? f(x) : x`, otherwise `seven(mul(zero()))` will break.

Comment: Thanks @georg, I missed that edge case. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: @NickParsons, thanks a lot, I have been cracking my mind how to do that. It's quite clear now, you saved my day!